# Grub2 reports physical volume pv0 not found when probing/installing

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, grub, grub2

I upgraded a Ubuntu Maverick to Precise server but I get the following error while updating grub:

```
error: physical volume pv0 not found.
```

Now, for my system I have /dev/sda through /dev/sde

- /dev/sda1 is a Linux partition for /boot
- and /dev/sda5 is an LVM partition
- /dev/sdb through /dev/sde are PVs for the LVM

By looking at my vg config, pv0 is /dev/sda5

I only have one Volume Group called "ns2" where the root (/) and some other logical volumes for the system.

I tried looking on the Web for help but they said I should upgrade to Grub2 as it is better to LVM support. I did that and I get the same error.
I haven't rebooted the server but I have the feeling it is not going to boot.
Still, I want to fix that error.

My boot partition is not in an LVM volume so even grub1 or grub2 should look at it without problems.

Any ideas?
I just tried reinstalling grub but I get the same error, still it seems to go "fine".

What can I check before rebooting?
This server is in another location and I have no remote access to the console, so I want to go there ready if something needs to be done.

**Edit**: Added more information http://pastebin.com/Smr1pB8W

**Edit**: Added pvs information http://pastebin.com/yubMd232

Comment: Output for egrep -v "^#|^$" /boot/grub/grub.cf ?

Comment: You can check it at http://pastebin.com/Smr1pB8W

Comment: How about the output of "ls -l $(pvs -v | awk '/lvm2/ {print $1}')" ?

Comment: Here is the output, http://pastebin.com/yubMd232

Comment: @zachmorgan When you have more rep you'll be able to ask for clarification using comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't reboot between upgrading LVM2/GRUB and the kernel.

You will want to "pin" an old grub version long enough to reboot your system into a current kernel version. At that point you should be good to unpin, upgrade grub and everything should be kosher.

Add this to `/etc/apt/preferences`:

---

```
# Force grub to 1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3
Package: grub-pc
Pin: release n=maverick
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

---

Now

```
 apt-get update && apt-get -s dist-upgrade
```

Assuming you get a line like `Inst grub-pc [ 1.98+20100804-5ubuntu3]
....` (and the resulting dependency shuffling doesn't break your
system... Watch for things like libc downgrades) you can `apt-get dist-upgrade` to force grub back to sanity. I would suggest running
`update-grub` one more time to make sure you're not walking into an
un-bootable situation.

Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: I downgrade it and the errors went away, I still need to be there physically just in case something happens. I'll come back later with an update.

Comment: I uninstalled the `grub-pc` package then pinned it down and installed the one from **maverick**. Everything is working now, I still want to try to update to the one from **precise** but right now I don't have to. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Like I mentioned above, you should be fine to change everything back to stable now. Grub is an incredibly resilient tool, it's unfortunate that the error messages are so cryptic at times. :)